# param is missing or the value is empty: status

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, parameters, missing-data

When I try to submit a new status I get the below.  I have a registration form that is working fine, not sure what is going on here.  Appreciate the help.

```
def status_params
  params.require(:status).permit(:type_id, :user_id)
end
```

and

```
def create
  @status = Status.new(status_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @status.save
```

The request

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
       "authenticity_token"=>"gZPV4FfSm2eb+pGPbAAqI4zA/LHJiAsRkHdJar/aU3G63oBiaLr55zPoRv3K+7EmelN2Nofj/CTZ+qPtoYih5w==",
     "type"=>{"user_id"=>"3"},
     "type_id"=>"Ocular",
     "commit"=>"Create Status"}
```

My View

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :user_id %><br>
    <%= select(:user_id, @user_options) %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :type_id %><br>
    <%= select_tag :type_id, options_for_select(mg_types) %>
  </div>
```

Comment: Cannot really follow what the problem is.

Comment: `"type"=>{"user_id"=>"3"}`, what is the "type"? I think it should be `"user_id"=>"3"`

Comment: The type allows me to choose from a list of current users, collections.

Answer (score 2):

Your params are not in `status` hash. So,
Try this -

```
 def status_params
   params.permit(:type_id, type[:user_id])
 end
```

Comment: that did not work for me.  I am using the collection drop down select in this form.  That is all that differs from the status form and the registration form.  Could that be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I can see multiple problems here:

1. The posted parameters are not wrapped in a `status` hash.
2. You are posting an attribute hash called `type` that contains a `user_id`, which is inconsistent with your whitelisted attributes.
3. You are also posting an attribute called `type_id` that contains a String (and not an id).
4. Posting both `type` and `type_id` conflicts because Rails will set these attributes on the `Status` model and one will probably override the other.

Comment: Why would these params for my registration form work then?
    def registration_params
         params.require(:registration).permit(:last, :first, :address, :city, :state, :postal, :country, :category)
    end

Comment: @StephenCagigal because those params wrapped in `registration` hash like - {:registration =>{:last => 'last_name',:first_name => 'first_name}}